Report total row data show incorrect in SSRS 2013
I have a report layout, which is shown below:

I have set both parameter PackCode and MagCode to NULL (@PackCode = NULL , @MagCode = NULL).
Before I change the page break option to (Between each instance of a group) and the Group Expression (group on : [PackCode]), my report data only show one row but I execute my SP exec rpt_sp_list @PackCode = NULL , @MagCode = NULL and it have 2,000+ rows.
The requirement is I want to page break each PackCode data and it should be shown on a new page in SSRS. After export to excel, the excel sheet name should be each PackCode name. In future, there will be as much as PackCode.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks a lot.

Edit your question to show some sample data from your SP output and also the report design, in design mode. Show row group properties for all row groups. Once you have done this I might be able to help.
